# Bootstrap navbar always collapsed

Tags: bootstrap-4

my navbar is always collapsed, I'not sure what is wrong, as I have copied the code from the bootstrap documentation website.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>GSD Lexi - German Shepherd Dog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>   
    <!-- /navbar -->
```

You can view the full code here: https://codepen.io/brianquan/pen/oJKdWx

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `bootstrap-alpha-6`, you cant use `navbar-expand-lg` this class for show your collapse menu, you need to use `navbar-toggleable-lg` for that.

it looks like below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>GSD Lexi - German Shepherd Dog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>   
    <!-- /navbar -->
```

updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdmRyg

Comment: you need to select my answer as best answer because another answer is not perfect answer for you, from my side